# Any R packages that can perform generalized linear mixed model with Firth correction?

Tags: r, mixed-model, genetics, case-control-study

I am performing a genetic association analysis with binary outcomes (case-control study) and would like to include a genetic relatedness matrix (GRM or kinship matrix) as a covariate along with others. One issue that arises is the case of perfect separation, where all or no individuals with a genotype has outcome of interest. These scenarios could be potentially interesting and I was wondering if there are any known packages that can handle GRMs and have the ability to perform Firth correction. All packages that I am aware of (GCTA, Fast-LMM, plink2, etc.) cannot perform this procedure.

Or, alternatively, are there any relevant methods that could avoid the perfect separation issue? One alternative I am thinking of pursuing is LEAP: https://github.com/omerwe/LEAP/.

Comment: Look into lasso, search this site.

Comment: Maybe, try Bayesian approach?